# SVG element's "as is" borders

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to create a gizmo to edit SVG objects.
Now, the problem I'm trying to solve right now is next:
I have an object. The gizmo appears around the object so the object can be scaled, translated and rotated. What I need to do is to find object's borders as is, because the gizmo should always appear as this: http://s16.postimage.org/kipdum2v9/example.png
(if anybody wanders, pink is the object, black stroke is the gizmo)

P.S. Please, do not suggest to use existing editors.

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using to generate SVGs for the object and the gizmo?

Comment: @user852798 The code is complex, mixed and includes many properties, so I can't cut it to post here a certain part. It has about 400 lines. The main idea of the gizmo is that it captures the mouse movement and scales, moves, or rotates the object. All these work fine. I only need to know, whether there is a way to know the extreme points of an object, or should I calculate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the *contact points* of your shapes with the bounding box.
To solve generally your problem seems rather difficult, also because SVG shapes definition can be *fuzzy* (filters, etc).

As long as your shapes are *paths*, a simple, yet approximate way, could make use of getPointAtLength method of interface [SVGPathElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathElement). Sample a reasonable number of points, and keep the extremals. Those should approximate the requested points.

Maybe you could make use of the values returned by getBBox() to refine the approximation.

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect()` really does the trick. Thanks a lot!